# Controlling both main text and math mode fonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex

I'm using a `scrartcl` document class and LuaLatex to write an article which contains math equations. I am required to use Arial as my main text font, which I've set using the package `fontspec` (to "unlock" the Arial font) and `\setmainfont{Arial}`. I can use "any" serif font for equations, so I've kept the default one.

Whenever I encounter multi-letter variables I'd like to use `\mathit{}` to avoid having space between each letter and still keep it in italics, but unfortunately then the font changes to Arial, instead of the math mode font:

[image: result1]

As I understand mathit is not supposed to change the font. I've tried to force the math font to change using `\setmathrm{Asana-Math}` (I don't have to use this one specifically, Asana Math is just the first font I've encountered in [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc) document under "Math fonts"), but then the normal math mode is still in the default font and everything else in Asana-Math WITHOUT italics (even `mathit`), see result:

[image: result2]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fontspec} % get additional fonts
\setmainfont{Arial} % sets the main font for the document
\setmathrm{Asana-Math} % change math mode font; only used in second result
\begin{document} 
    Normal text.
    
    $f = MATHMODE$ 
    
    $\mathit{f = mathit}$
    
    $\mathrm{f = mathrm}$
\end{document}
```

How can I have control over both my main text font and the math mode font? How can I get both the math mode and the result of `\mathit{}` in my desired math font and in italics?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mico’s solution works, but here’s a more comprehensive set of options.

Traditional TeX used commands such as `\mathit`, `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` both for words in math mode and also for math symbols.  The `unicode-math` package attempts to separate these two things.  Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\noindent\texttt{\textbackslash mathit} \(\mathit{iff}\) \\
\texttt{\textbackslash symit} \(\symit{iff}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]

By default in `fontspec`, `\mathit` gives you the first (*iff* typeset as a word, not the product of the three math symbols *i*, *f* and *f*).  As you’ve seen, it defaults to using the text font for `\mathrm`, `\mathit` and `\mathbf`.  Here are some ways to override that.

#### The Simple Fix

You’re using `\mathit` and want it to behave like `\symit`.  There’s a `unicode-math` package option for that, `mathit=sym`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathfont{Fira Math} % Or your math font of choice.

\begin{document}
\noindent Arial \textit{Italic} \\
\texttt{\textbackslash mathit} \(\mathit{iff} \) \\
\texttt{\textbackslash symit} \(\symit{iff}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial + Fira sample]

Here. I used Fira Math as a sans-serif math font that matches reasonably well.  You mentioned that you’re using any serif math font; the default for Office’s Equation Editor is Cambria Math.

If you still want to use words in math mode, and have them appear in the main text font, you can use the commands `\textnormal` and `\textit` in math mode.

If you’re using `\mathit` this way, you might also expect `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` to work the same way, so the command you want might in fact be

```
\usepackage[mathbf=sym, mathit=sym, mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
```

#### Say Precisely What You Mean

You want the behavior of `\symit`, rather than the default behavior of `\mathit` under `unicode-math`, which isn’t precisely the same as the default behavior of `\mathit` under other packages.  Your code will be much less likely to break unexpectedly when you copy it into another document if you write `\symit` or `\textit` in your source, instead of the ambiguous `\mathit`.

#### Change the `\mathit` Font

The `\setmathrm` command from `fontspec` also lets you set the `\mathit`, `\mathbf` and `\mathbfit` fonts, as the `ItalicFont`, `BoldFont` and `BoldItalicFont` of `\mathrm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathfont{Fira Math} % Or your math font of choice.
\setmathrm{FiraSans}[ Extension = .otf ,
                      UprightFont = *-Regular ,
                      ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
                      BoldFont = *-Bold,
                      BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]

\begin{document}
\noindent Arial \textit{Italic} \\
\texttt{\textbackslash mathit} \(\mathit{iff} \) \\
\texttt{\textbackslash symit} \(\symit{iff}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Arial + Fira sample]

#### Use a Legacy Math Font

You don’t have to use `unicode-math`.  If you load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option, it will leave the existing definition of `\mathit` unchanged.  Here is one of the few combinations of legacy sans-serif math packages that works, more or less:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage[tx]{sfmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\noindent Arial \textit{Italic} \\
\texttt{\textbackslash mathit} \(\mathit{iff} \) \\
\texttt{\textbackslash textit} \(\textit{iff}\)

\( \displaystyle\int \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \sum_{S} y(t) \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Newtxsf + Arial]

Answer (score 2):

First, do load the `unicode-math` package (which, incidentally, loads `fontspec` automatically). Second, I suggest you replace the legacy commands `\mathit` and `\mathrm` with `\symit` and `\symrm` (which, you guessed it, are provided by the `unicode-math` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec automatically
\setmainfont{Arial} % sets the main font for the document
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document} 

\obeylines % just for this test document
Normal text.
$f = MATHMODE$ 
$\symit{f = mathit}$
$\symrm{f = mathrm}$
$\mathit{f = mathit}$
$\mathrm{f = mathrm}$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The unicode-math package offers the following five new basic commands: `\symup` (alias: `\symrm`), `\symit`, `\symbf`, `\symsf`, and `\symtt`. There are quite a few additional new commands, listed in Table 1 of the package's user guide. Here's a screenshot of Table 1:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I've tried it and found that the normal math mode and `\symit` look exactly the same (if I use the same example word, I should've done that earlier). The original reason why I did this was to have the characters of multi-letter variables close together, like a normal text (but still in math mode font and italics). This is particularly an issue for variables in all capital letters. It this possible in any way? Or is it a general restriction of the font?

Comment: Is the `\symrm` command undocumented? I have used it in the past and it works, but now I cannot find it in the unicode-math package documentation for some reason.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis - It's true that `\symrm` is not documented the user guide of the now-current version of `unicode-math` (*viz.*, `2020/01/31 v0.8q`). I can only guess that I learned about `\symrm` some time ago, while using an older version of the package. FWIW, `\symrm` and `\symup` do seem the produce the same output if a serif math font is in use. (I don't think I have any sans-serif math fonts; hence, I can't check the conjecture for a sans-serif math font...)